# Delete with a subquery give an invalid path

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I use spring boot 2 with jpa and hibernate.
I try to do a delete.

My class

```
public Scpi{
    @Id
    ....
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "scpi")
    private Set<Asi> asi = new HashSet<>();

    ...
}

public Asi{
    @Id
    ....
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Spi spi;

    ...
}
```

My delete

```
@Modifying
@Query("delete from Scpi scpi where scpi.id in ( select spci2.id from Scpi scpi2 inner Join spci2.asi asi inner Join asi.spi spi where spi.id= ?1)")
```

Error I get

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.InvalidPathException: Invalid path:
>   'spci2.asi'

Any idea?

Comment: seems typo in your sql please check my answer posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems typo in your sql, it should be `scpi2.asi` instead of `spci2.asi` and same with `scpi2.id`.

so correct delete statement would be:

```
@Modifying
@Query("delete from Scpi scpi where scpi.id in ( select scpi2.id from Scpi scpi2 inner Join scpi2.asi asi inner Join asi.spi spi where spi.id= ?1)")
```